# Vue 3, Pinia getter not updating vue reactive variable when it changes

Tags: vuejs3, vite, pinia, vue-reactivity, tauri

I'm trying to make a state controlled application. It is a tauri app but i don't think my problem is relative with that. My app checking system status by some awaited process and sets appStatus which using by some other components. appStatus state was an object but i tried to seperate status prop but still same problem. what am i doing wrong?

general.js- pinia store

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useGeneralStore = defineStore('general', {
  state: () => ({
    appStatus: 'loading',
    appStatusData: {
      status: 'loading',
      license_number: '',
      days_left: 0,
      valid_until: '',
    },
    showOverlay: false,
  }),
  getters: {
    getShowOverlay: (state) => state.showOverlay,
    disabledWhen: (state) => {
      return (conditions) => {
        if (conditions.includes(state.appStatus)) return true;
        return false;
      };
    },
  },
  actions: {
    setAppStatus(value) {
      this.appStatus = value;
    },
    setShowOverlay(value) {
      this.showOverlay = value;
    },
  },
});
```

---

App.vue - checking status of system on start

```
....
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { Command } from '@tauri-apps/api/shell';

import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
import { useGeneralStore } from './store/general';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const store = useGeneralStore();
const { setDialog } = store;
const { showOverlay, appStatus, appStatusData, fernetKey } = storeToRefs(store);

onMounted(async () => {
  showOverlay.value = true;
  const command = Command.sidecar('binaries/app', ['status', fernetKey.value]);
  let out = await command.execute();
  if (out.code !== 0) {
    setDialog(out.stderr);
    return;
  }
  out = JSON.parse(out.stdout);
  appStatus.value = out.status;
  appStatusData.value = out;
  // store.setAppStatus(JSON.parse(out.stdout));
  // appStatus.value = JSON.parse(out.stdout)
  showOverlay.value = false;
});
</script>
...
```

---

ActionTabs.vue - child component. tabs system.

```
<template>
  <div class="actions_side w-12 font-montserrat-regular relative">
    <TabView :active-index="enabledIndex">
      <TabPanel
        :disabled="tab.disabled"
        v-for="tab in actionTabs"
        :key="tab.title"
        :header="tab.title"
      >
        <component :is="tab.component" />
      </TabPanel>
    </TabView>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed, reactive } from 'vue';
import Activation from '../components/Activation.vue';
import Deactivation from '../components/Deactivation.vue';
import Install from '../components/Install.vue';

import { useGeneralStore } from '../store/general';

import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
const store = useGeneralStore()
const { appStatus, disabledWhen } = storeToRefs(store)


const actionTabs = reactive([
  {
    title: 'Activate',
    component: Activation,
    // disabled: ['active', 'notFound', 'loading'].includes(appStatus.value.status),
    disabled: disabledWhen.value(['active', 'notFound', 'loading']),
  },
  {
    title: 'Deactivate',
    component: Deactivation,
    disabled: disabledWhen.value(['deactive', 'notFound', 'loading']),
    // disabled: ['deactive', 'notFound', 'loading'].includes(appStatus.value.status),
  },
  {
    title: 'Install',
    component: Install,
    disabled: true,
  },
  {
    title: 'Update',
    component: Activation,
    disabled: true,
  },
]);

const enabledIndex = computed(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < actionTabs.length; i++) {
    if (!actionTabs[i].disabled) return i;
  }
});
</script>
```

- tried to make reactive to ref.
- changed getter to local controls (commented codes still there)
- seperate primal value from object.
- changed the state value with a button and assert that the state is changing correctly.